# Simple drop-down list slow on web page - Chrome and Edge

Tags: html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, html-select

I have noticed that drop-down lists (even small lists) display their options quite slowly in Chrome and Edge. This only happens on pages with several hundred lines of content. Please look at the following Fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/my34vzo0/2/

```
<select>

    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>

</select>

<br/>
aaaaa<br />
aaaaa<br />
aaaaa<br />
aaaaa<br />
aaaaa<br />
aaaaa<br />
aaaaa<br />
etc...(about 500 lines should do it!)
```

When you click on the drop-down there is a short, but noticeable delay before the list of options is displayed.This becomes more apparent if you click the list several times in succession. If you are able to compare this behaviour in IE, you will see the difference.

Very grateful for any help.

Comment: No delay when I click it.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a [mre] here on Stack Overflow instead of making volunteers go to another site to reproduce. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it appears that this issue only occurs on my work computer (which is connected via VPN/Firewall/background software etc.) I have no idea why this slows the rendering of the drop-down options (bearing in mind the Select list is static HTML), but I will close this question. Sorry again.